# Functions not working on buttons in Unity game engine. Why?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I did transition animation between scenes in *Unity*. When I press a button transition animation will play and after a second another scene will be loaded.

The problem is functions assigned to buttons are not working.

[image: Why Functions not working]

Comment: You'll see SceneManager.LoadScene("AnotherScene"); I did it for try but itsn't what i expected its working but not good and itsn't working without this.

Comment: in the future place all code in your post not in an external link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you have to assign your coroutine (placeloader) to a ienumerator, then call startcoroutine on the ienumerator.

```
private IEnumerator coroutine;
```

//when you want to go to the other scene do

```
coroutine = PlaceLoader("AnotherScene");
StartCoroutine(coroutine);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html